# What are the ways to call a smart contract function during development?

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, ganache

What are the ways to call a smart contract function during development using Truffle simulated VM with a GUI interface (like Remix or EtherScan offer)?

I know I could use CLI options like [Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts) and [Open Zeppelin SDK](https://openzeppelin.com/sdk/). I also could develop unit tests, but I think it is productive to use a GUI to execute some tests during development.

Obs.: I do not have a GUI in my application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[I wrote an article](https://medium.com/authereum/debugging-solidity-with-a-gui-remix-and-ganache-c6c16488fcfd) about how to do just this!

You can use [`remixd`](https://github.com/ejwessel/GanacheTimeTraveler#reverttosnapshotid_to_revert_to) and [`remix`](https://remix.ethereum.org) to test and debug your contracts with a GUI (remix). The steps to do this are:

1. Install `remixd` with `npm install -g remixd`
2. Run `remixd` with `remixd -s <absolute-path> --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`
3. Attach your project to remix.ethereum.org
4. Run ganache-cli in the terminal with `ganache-cli`
5. Choose “Web3 Provider” as your “Environment” in remix
6. Test your code with a GUI (remix)

The article dives deeper into each step, but you should be able to achieve your goals with just those 6 steps!